# Parsing an oauth token in my own code

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an application (WPF C#, asp.net web api 2 on the server) where the user logs in, and may login as an administrator. And then I want them to be able to logout, and the login as another user but still complete some administrative tasks. For that I thought the easiest way to do it would be to pass through to my Web API function on the server the oauth token returned when loggged in as the administrator.  Then I should be able to read the token, verify that it is valid and check that the user is an administrator.

However, I can't find any obvious way that I can do this.

Is there any easy way that I can do this?

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this.  It depends on how you are creating your oauth token and what information can be retrieved from it.  Do you have some sample code that you can post of what you've tried?

Comment: @Karen B,
I pretty much have no idea where to start.Most of this is a blackbox to me. I haven't been able to find sample code that would allow me to get anything out of the oauth token. Token is created a OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider derived class, in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials with this code:
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
context.Validated(ticket);
context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

What I need to do is opposite of whatever happens to create the token, but not sure how to do that...

Comment: are you getting the token from another application or are you writing both the consumer and provider code?  If you're writing both, then you can determine what data points make up the token, what the encryption key and salt is, then you can reverse it on the other side.  If you're not writing both, then you would need to get that information from whoever is providing the token.

Comment: Also, a good starting place is this Microsoft tutorial: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server.

Comment: I'm controlling both, but I have no idea what the salt or key or anything like that is because it's all done in the ASP WebApi code.  I have a read of the document and see it helps.  The code is being sent from the server and then sent back to the server by the client so everything will be happening on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is VERY easy, here's what you need to do: 
`Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(adminToken);`

Where Startup is the default MVC class containing ConfigureAuth.